# TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function - Existing solutions not working - problems with Yeoman generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, yeoman

I am following the highcharts get started tutorial here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

**For some reason the code works in a separate HTML file, but not when it's part of my Yeoman built web application**

I've fallen at the first hurdle and get the following error: 
TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function

My code is below and here is the full error:

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
>           at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at  (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:328:5),
>   :2:21)
>           at fire (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3099:30)
>           at Object.self.add [as done] (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3145:7)
>           at jQuery.fn.ready (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3378:25)
>           at jQuery.fn.init (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2821:16)
>           at jQuery (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:76:10)
>           at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:328:5),
>   :1:1)
>           at eval (native)
>           at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:328:5)
>           at jQuery.fn.extend.domManip (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5435:16)

**There are multiple other posts about this** -  however none of the solutions have worked for me, can't see what I'm doing wrong here, all I've done is copy the tutorial.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script>$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try to put your js code and the <script src=> before the body tag

Comment: Do you run in https environment? It's possible that highcharts would not be load because your site is https and script is http

Comment: Please try to provide the src without the protocol: `<script  src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>`

Comment: or it might be that you haven't properly imported highcharts library?

Comment: I've followed the tutorial and included the script as they've told me to

Comment: its seems like you are importing jquery from bower component directory, you sure you have `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and not `<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` ?

Comment: I'm sure, but maybe it defaults to another call of <script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> elsewhere?

Comment: Any chance Yeoman does any magic on script loading? Like making them async? Would injecting the highcharts raw code in the head script work?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script>$(function () { 
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

works fine. Just removed the double closing brackets from closing html tag.

Comment: this is not an answer and this is not the porblem.

Comment: @John sorry then. I thought the code wasn't running but it's running here.

Comment: yes, the OP code is clean and its working, like others said its a protocol issues